# Extended Combobox in SWT

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I looking for Commbobox in which I can change Font property for some items.

Example:

- First item: bold, font colour: red
- Second item: italic, font colour: dark

Or: How to use org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo widget to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [Creating Your Own Widgets using SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm).